# how to disable factory reset on galaxy tab4 with custom ROM

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, galaxy

I rooted my device (galaxt tab4 t230NU) and I just upgraded android 4.2 to 5 with Custom ROM. I  want to disable factory reset option from Custom ROM. any Idea how it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory reset is performed in Recovery Mode: it can be done directly in recovery GUI or by selecting an option in Setting app that create command file in Cache partition and reboots to Recovery to read this file. So, in order in disable factory reset, I suggest wiping your device Recovery partition.

Comment: While this advice is technically correct, it's also a horrible idea. Getting rid of recovery mode means that next time there is something wrong with your device, you won't be able to recover at all from it. Better advice would be to prevent access to the physical buttons of the tablet that enable recovery mode. If the OP is building a real physical kiosk that is meant to be unattended, then that should be possible. After all, it's not like this is a new problem. Someone else must have solved this problem and posted a custom ROM on XDA like that already.

Comment: We already talk about custom ROM here, so you can always flash a recovery image in case of a problem (unless you've ruined your bootloader...)

Comment: if there is a method to flash a recovery image without going into recovery mode, then I do not know that method. If such a method exists, then forget what I said.

Comment: Can you please explain more? how can I wipe my recovery partition? seems to be a good option for me.

Comment: You can flash a recovery image in bootloader mode.

Comment: To wipe your recovery you need to find the partition device (it's device specific) and then you can use dd command to overwrite it.

Comment: On bootloader I went to file explorer and I removed recovery folder but I am still able to factory reset it. Any idea?

Comment: Bootloader is a boot mode that allow flashing a partition, it doesn't contains file explorer. Recovery is an image file stored in recovery partition, not in a directory. Please try what I've suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: Is it something possible on TeamWin? or I should use Odin? sorry for asking bunch of question I am not really a programmer. I really appreciate if you can help me figure this thing out.

Comment: Can I access bootloader on galaxytab4 T230nu?

Comment: Yes it's possible on TWRP. Google how to find recovery partition device (probably under /dev/block/). Use dd command to fill device content (using /dev/zero for example)

Comment: @Daniel, on TERP I found: dev/block/platform/soc.2/by-name/recovery. when I click on recovery it gives me these options: copy file,move,chmod 755,chmod,delete,rename file. I tried to delete it but each time I system reboot, it recreate it.

Comment: and when I click on chmod, it asks me to put 4 digit number. the default is "0000".

Comment: Open terminal emulator or adb and use the command: dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/soc.2/by-name/recovery

Comment: I change the chmod of recovery to 0777 to be able to write. then inside of the adb shell to write : dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/soc.2/by-name/recovery  but it says cannot open recovery the permission is denied :(

Comment: that problem resolved but still: rm/soc.2/by-name/recovery: write error: No space left on device

Comment: You can't remove a block device, just overwrite it using dd command. That should be enough

Comment: I just used this command:dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/block/platform/soc.2/by-name/recovery. but it gives me error write error: No space left on device –

Comment: Its OK, that means you wrote zeroes on your entire recovery partition

Comment: so it did not work. I was able to factory reboot it again :(

Answer (score 0):

I think this is likely to be impossible; the whole point is that there should always be a way to get back to the basic system, otherwise mistakes would totally brick the device.

I have looked into this kind of thing for a client where we were trying to develop a kiosk app that could not be subverted.  Our conclusion was that Android devices belong to the user and can (and should) always be able to be factory reset by design.  In the end, we got to the point of accepting this and just locking out trivial attempts to subvert our app.

Comment: But I searched a lot and figured out it is possible with custom ROM.

Answer (score 0):

Lollipop introduced [Factory Reset Protection](http://www.androidcentral.com/factory-reset-protection-what-you-need-know), which you [might be able to use](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6172890?hl=en-GB).

Answer (score 0):

This question probably better posted on XDA, unless you have compiled the custom rom from source. Knowing Galaxy devices and lack of platform sources - you didn't.
In any case, the solution is simple. You need to decompile SecSettings.apk using apktool, find relevant layout in resources and remove layout which is responsible (when clicked) for reset sequence initiation. You might need to update public ids file as well. Please search xda for more info on modding decompiled apks. This is fairly a hacking and should not be asked OR answered here.
Just a note, those questions probably don't belong here. And the factory resset can still be performed from recovery (custom or stock). Sp disabling it from settings is really not a solution.